# Object's data tag being appended

Tags: html, silverlight

I am creating a silverlight control using the following syntax

```
object width="100%" height="100%"
        data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
        type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
```

When I run this locally, it works, but when I run it on our server, the data attribute becomes:

```
data="[company url]data:application/x-silverlight-2,
```

This causes a 400 error. Any insight would be very helpful.

Comment: As this attribute is optional, I removed it. However, it is supposed to help hint for performance. So, any help would be appreciated